# How to convert delete+insert SQL into DBT module

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I'm learning DBT and would like to rewrite following Snowflake procedure with DBT model.
Unfortunately I don't know how to express SQL delete/inserts in DBT.
Here is my procedure:

```
create or replace procedure staging.ingest_google_campaigns_into_master()
    returns varchar
    language sql
as
$$
    begin
    DELETE FROM GOOGLE_ADWORD_CAMPAIGN
           WHERE DT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ORIGINALDATE AS DT FROM GOOGLEADWORDS_CAMPAIGN);
    INSERT INTO GOOGLE_ADWORD_CAMPAIGN
        SELECT DISTINCT *
        FROM
            (
               SELECT  g.* ,
                       YEAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_PART(EPOCH_SECOND, ORIGINALDATE::TIMESTAMP)::VARCHAR)) AS YEAR,
                       LPAD(MONTH(TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_PART(EPOCH_SECOND, ORIGINALDATE::TIMESTAMP)::VARCHAR)),2,0) AS MONTH,
                       LPAD(DAY(TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_PART(EPOCH_SECOND, ORIGINALDATE::TIMESTAMP)::VARCHAR)),2,0) AS DAY,
                       TO_DATE(DATE_PART(EPOCH_SECOND, ORIGINALDATE::TIMESTAMP)::VARCHAR) AS DT

               FROM GOOGLEADWORDS_CAMPAIGN g
            ) t;
    end;
$$
;
```

The procedure first remove old rows from table GOOGLE_ADWORD_CAMPAIGN and later replace them with the fresh one.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is called an "incremental" materialization in dbt. See [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models) for more background.

On Snowflake, there are a few different "strategies" you can use for incremental materializations. One strategy is called `delete+insert`, which does exactly what your stored procedure does. Another option is `merge`, which may perform better.

Adapting your code to dbt would look like this:

```sql
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='ORIGINALDATE',
        incremental_strategy='delete+insert',
    )
}}

SELECT DISTINCT 
    g.* ,
    YEAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_PART(EPOCH_SECOND, ORIGINALDATE::TIMESTAMP)::VARCHAR)) AS YEAR,
    LPAD(MONTH(TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_PART(EPOCH_SECOND, ORIGINALDATE::TIMESTAMP)::VARCHAR)),2,0) AS MONTH,
    LPAD(DAY(TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_PART(EPOCH_SECOND, ORIGINALDATE::TIMESTAMP)::VARCHAR)),2,0) AS DAY,
    TO_DATE(DATE_PART(EPOCH_SECOND, ORIGINALDATE::TIMESTAMP)::VARCHAR) AS DT
FROM GOOGLEADWORDS_CAMPAIGN g
```

Note that this assumes there is just a single record in `GOOGLEADWORDS_CAMPAIGN` for each `ORIGINALDATE` -- if that is not true, you will want to substitute your own `unique_key` in the config block.

This also assumes that `GOOGLEADWORDS_CAMPAIGN` contains a sliding date window already. If that isn't the case, and you want to filter the dates contained in that table (and only update a subset of the data), you want to add a conditional `WHERE` statement when the model is built in incremental mode:

```sql
...
FROM GOOGLEADWORDS_CAMPAIGN g
{% if is_incremental() %}
WHERE
    DT >= (SELECT MAX(DT) FROM {{ this }}) - INTERVAL '7 DAYS'
{% endif %}
```